# How to read and write csv file when it is opened with Excel by the user in parallel with C#?

Tags: c#, excel, csv

This is the first question I asked on stackoverflow, very exciting. So sorry about my grammar and other type mistakes, I would appreciate if you correct them. I want to write a program that reads a csv file if it exists in the specific folder first, stores it in List variable, add some new lines and writes it to the same file. This process will be repeated continuously in a while block.

While the file is being read and written by the program, if it is opened with Notepad, it doesn't give an error and the program could access the file in parallel. But if it is opened with Office Excel, program gives error that says "file access is denied because it is used by another process..". I want to ask you that:

1) Is it possible to give priority to the program, so program can still access the file but user cannot? Or is it possible both program and user can access the file?

2) If the solution is opening the file with Notepad, is there a way to set default program for this file as Notepad? Or how can I change default program for csv files as Notepad from C#?

Reading and writing parts of the code is as bellows:

```
    List<string> csvLines = new List<string>();
    string address = folderpath + @"\PLC_LOGLARI";
    if (!Directory.Exists(address))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(address);

    string fileAddress = address + @"\" + fileName + "_" + machineNo + "_1.csv";

    if (Directory.EnumerateFiles(address).Any(f => f.Contains(fileName + "_" + machineNo)))
    {
        string[] addressArray = Directory.GetFiles(address, fileName + "_" + machineNo + "*.*");
        FileInfo fileInformation = new FileInfo(addressArray[addressArray.Length - 1]);
        long fileSize = fileInformation.Length;
        if (fileSize > 5000000)
        {
            int fileNo = int.Parse(addressArray[addressArray.Length - 1].Substring(addressArray[addressArray.Length - 1].LastIndexOf('_') + 1, 1)) + 1;
            fileAddress = addressArray[addressArray.Length - 1].Substring(0, addressArray[addressArray.Length - 1].LastIndexOf('_') + 1) + fileNo.ToString() + ".csv";
        }
        else
        {
            fileAddress = addressArray[addressArray.Length - 1];
            csvLines = File.ReadAllLines(address).ToList();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        string[] headings = makeHeadings();
        csvLines.Add(headings[0]);
        csvLines.Add(headings[1]);
    }
    string newLine = "";

    // some operations and calculations for newLine
    // some operations and calculations for newLine
    // some operations and calculations for newLine

    newLine = newLine.Substring(1, newLine.Length-1);
    csvLines.Add(newLine);
    File.WriteAllLines(fileAddress, csvLines.ToArray());
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Since you are writing a log file, have you considered any of the very common existing libraries that can help you with that, avoiding many of the pitfalls that you are now experiencing?

Comment: As for reading a log file that is being written, consider using Notepad++. It's basically your standard Notepad, but on steroids. One useful thing it does is that it notifies you when a file has changed and enables you to reload it - so you can monitor the log very easily. Changing the extension from .csv to .log or .txt would stop Excel opening the file, btw.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually it writes 36 byte to the file in binary format for each new line, that means 288 columns, and the period is 500 mili-seconds, so there are too much rows and columns in the file and the best way to view the data is using Excel I suppose, that's why I choose csv extension.

Answer (score 0):

For question 2: In order to change the default program, if you are using Windows, you could click start and find/type 'Default Programs'. Depending on the version of windows, basically find 'Associate a file type of protocol with a program' or 'choose a default application by file type' and adjust the csv file to use a new default program.

I would be very careful if both program and notepad are able accessing the file in the same time. The reason why it was blocked in the first place was to prevent overridding the content of the file, thus probably test it first if you open it in the program and notepad. Then the program make some update - and you also make a different update with the notepad. Would both changes be recorded? As I suspect the 'last save' win in which you may lost some of your changes.

For question 1: I was guessing that whoever open the file first got the lock of that file. As such, if Excel was opening the file - then the program would have that error. Vice versa, if the program had opened the file - then the Excel may have problem opening that file. I'm not sure how to give priority to the program.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I know how to change default program for an extension from Windows, manually. I click right on the file, choose Properties and change "open with" feature with different program. But I would like to ask that is it possible to change default program for the **only**  csv file that the program writes **from C#?** Or is it possible to change default program for all csv files as Notepad **from C# again?**

Comment: There is typically no "flag" in a CSV file which will indicate to the OS the source of the file, so any default program you pick will be used for all CSV files.